# Linkedin API throttle limit

Tags: linkedin-api, throttling

Recently I was developing an application using Linkedin people-search API. Documentation says that a developer registration has 1 lac API calls per day, but when I have registered this API, and ran a python script, after some 300 calls it says throttle limit exceeds. 
Did anyone face such kind of issue using Linkedin API, comments are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Lac" as in 100K? you may want to clarify that.

Answer (score 8):

It's been a while but the stats suggest people still look at this and I'm experimenting with the LinkedIn API and can provide some more detail.

The typical throttles are stated as both a max (e.g. 100K) and a per-user-token number (e.g. 500). Those numbers together mean you can get up to a maximum of 100,000 calls per day to the API but even as a developer a single user token means a maximum of 500 per day.

I ran into this, and after setting up a barebones app and getting some users I can confirm a daily throttle of several thousands of API calls. [Deleted discussion of what was probably, upon further consideration, an accidental back door in the LinkedIn API.]

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Throttle Limits](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/throttle-limits) published by [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/):

> LinkedIn API keys are throttled by default. The throttles are designed
>   to ensure maximum performance for all developers and to protect the
>   user experience of all users on LinkedIn.
>
> There are three types of throttles applied to all API keys:
>
> - Application throttles: These throttles limit the number of each API call your application can make using its API key.
> - User throttles: These throttles limit the number of calls for any individual user of your application. User-level throttles serve
>     several purposes, but in general are implemented where there is a
>     significant potential impact to the user experience for LinkedIn
>     users.
> - Developer throttles: For people listed as developers on their API keys, they will see user throttles that are approximately four times
>     higher than the user throttles for most calls. This gives you extra
>     capacity to build and test your application. Be aware that the
>     developer throttles give you higher throttle limits as a developer of
>     your application. But your users will experience the User throttle
>     limits, which are lower. Take care to make sure that your application
>     functions correctly with the User throttle limits, not just for the
>     throttle limits for your usage as a developer.
>
> **Note**: To view current API usage of your application and to ensure you haven't hit any throttle limits, visit
>   https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps and click on "Usage & Limits".

Answer (score 0):

The throttle limit for individual users of People Search is 100, with 400 being the limit for the person that is associated with the Application as the developer:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits

When you run into a limit, view the api usage for the application on the [application page](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer) to see which throttle you are hitting.

Comment: This link is no more active.