# Headless Chrome Driver not working for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare

I am current having an issue with my scraper when I set `options.add_argument("--headless")`. However, it works perfectly fine when it is removed. Could anyone advise how I can achieve the same results with headless mode?

Below is my python code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver as wireDriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    
chromedriverPath = '/Users/applepie/Desktop/chromedrivermac'

    def scraper(search):

    mit = "https://orbit-kb.mit.edu/hc/en-us/search?utf8=✓&query="  # Empty search on mit site
    mit += "+".join(search) + "&commit=Search"
    results = []

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1440, 900")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path= chromedriverPath)

    driver.get(mit)
    # Wait 20 seconds for page to load
    timeout = 20
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "header")))
        search_results = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-results")
        for result in search_results.find_elements_by_class_name("search-result"):
            resultObject = {
                "url": result.find_element_by_class_name('search-result-link').get_attribute("href")
            }
            results.append(resultObject)
        driver.quit()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
        driver.quit()

    return results
```

Here is also a screenshot of when I `print(driver.page_source)` after `get()`:

[image]

Comment: can you explain what the issue actually is?

Comment: @PApostol, the scraper is not returning any results when I add `options.add_argument("--headless")`. However, it works fine when `options.add_argument("--headless")` is removed

Comment: maybe try with `options.headless = True` instead of `options.add_argument("--headless")` to see if there is a difference. Also consider including an example people could run to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PApostol `options.headless = True` does not work too.

Comment: @ApplePie Take a screenshot or print the `driver.page_source` after `get()` to confirm if `get()` is successful.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have added a screenshot above.

Answer (score 4):

This screenshot...

[image: screenshot]

...implies that the [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) have detected your requests to the website as an automated bot and subsequently denying you the access to the application.

---

### Solution

In these cases the a potential solution would be to use the [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) in [headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368002/which-drivers-support-no-browser-headless-testing/48368054#48368054) mode to initialize the [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) browsing context.

[undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) is an optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io. It automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

- Code Block:

  ```
  import undetected_chromedriver as uc
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.headless = True
  driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get(url)
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium app redirect to Cloudflare page when hosted on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842858/selenium-app-redirect-to-cloudflare-page-when-hosted-on-heroku/64960149#64960149)
- [How to bypass being rate limited ..HTML Error 1015 using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128879/how-to-bypass-being-rate-limited-html-error-1015-using-python/65136081#65136081)

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)
`

Comment: @ApplePie `SSLCertVerificationError` is a certificate issue which is a much granular issue compared to this generic question on accessing the application through `headless` mode. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a super old question but recently (2023) they upgraded the headless chrome which now allows headless to work with extensions.

See this [webpage](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/) for more details.

Just replace the headless option above with the below.

```
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
```

According to the website if you just use `--headless`, it still uses the old version and you have to explicitly point it to the new version to work.