# How can I block all Selenium bots?

Tags: selenium, bots, user-agent, cloudflare, rate-limiting

How can I block all selenium bots? I want to block all selenium project.

**Explanation:**

I have very big website for streaming anime etc. Minimum Monthly 30 million hit guest and member.

Some websites grab from our site video links. Using with selenium bot

Before we did check and block, user agent, rate limit, session id check many bots blocked but now someone still grab, change proxy IP, session-id again send the request for grab. So he/she bypass our rate limit etc tracker.

How can I block all selenium bots? I want to block all selenium project.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to block the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) bots totally as there are specific measures to bypass almost all the bot detecting mechanisms. A couple of examples:

- The [`navigator.webdriver` flag can be modified to prevent Selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904).
- The [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) of *Google Chrome* [used by Selenium can be changed for each execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254).
- The useragent of [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) [used by Selenium can be changed amid execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490495/how-to-change-the-user-agent-using-selenium-and-python/62491863#62491863).
- Using [rotating proxies to avoid detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409418/how-to-rotate-selenium-webrowser-ip-address/59410739#59410739).
- Detection of bots by [cloudflare](/questions/tagged/cloudflare) [can also be bypassed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636102/cloudflare-and-chromedriver-cloudflare-distinguishes-between-chromedriver-and/65637899#65637899).
- Detection of [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) by *Cloudflare* [can also be bypassed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585702/headless-chrome-driver-not-working-for-selenium/65586349#65586349).
- *`Error 1015: You are being rate limited`* by *Cloudflare* [can also be bypassed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128879/how-to-bypass-being-rate-limited-html-error-1015-using-python/65136081#65136081).

---

### tl; dr

[Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)