# Cloudflare and Chromedriver - cloudflare distinguishes between chromedriver and genuine chrome?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare, undetected-chromedriver

I would like to use chromedriver to scrape some stories from fanfiction.net.
I try the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

path = 'D:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)
url1 = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8832472'
url2 = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5218118'

browser.get(url1)
time.sleep(5)
browser.get(url2)
```

The first link opens (sometimes I have to wait 5 seconds). When I want to load the second url, cloudflare intervens and wants me to solve captchas - which are not solvable, atleast cloudflare does not recognize this.
This happens also, if I enter the links manually in chromedriver (so in the GUI). However, if I do the same things in normal chrome, everything works just as fine (I do not even get the waiting period on the first link) - even in private mode and all cookies deleted. I could reproduce this on several machines.
Now my question: To my intuition, chromedriver was just the normal chrome browser which allowed to be controlled. What is the difference to normal chrome, how does Cloudflare distinguish both, and how can I mask my chromedriver as normal chrome? (I do not intend to load many pages in very short time, so it should not look like a bot).
I hope my question is clear

Comment: this is bot detection on the site... (I don't think cloudflare in particular has anything to do with it, but a feature that sites can use) The difference is that in one case injections are made into the DOM. That session can be known as "bot-controlled"... the captcha will never solve in that session. If you start your browser manually the site does not detect you as a bot (cause you aren't!) and you can solve the captcha if it appears. (chromedriver launches and then interacts with the browser... it's a separate executable and there is a localhost communication between the driver and browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

[image: Checking your browser before accessing]

...implies that the [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) have detected your requests to the website as an automated bot and subsequently denying you the access to the application.

---

### Solution

In these cases the a potential solution would be to use the [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) to initialize the *Chrome Browsing Context*.

[undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) is an optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io. It automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

- Code Block:

  ```
  import undetected_chromedriver as uc
  from selenium import webdriver
  import time

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  url1 = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8832472'
  url2 = 'https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5218118'
  driver.get(url1)
  time.sleep(5)
  driver.get(url2)
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium app redirect to Cloudflare page when hosted on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842858/selenium-app-redirect-to-cloudflare-page-when-hosted-on-heroku/64960149#64960149)
- [How to bypass being rate limited ..HTML Error 1015 using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128879/how-to-bypass-being-rate-limited-html-error-1015-using-python/65136081#65136081)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!
Just out of curiosity, how exactly do they (cloudflare) recognize that I use bot-software?

Comment: @Tamar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/41220267

Comment: Today undetected_chromedriver in my case is detected by cloudflare, is there some update for this ? thanks

Comment: @PawelW There are so many other approaches to avoid detection.

Comment: Cloudflare track signals from millions of websites, that way the anti-bot tool works very well.