# May I be rate limited by using Selenium for webscraping on websites?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rate-limiting

I know there are rate limits for when you send get requests to a website, but does it apply to selenium? Can I get limited for that?

For example, in the above code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\path\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://google.com/")
while True:
  driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="link")
```

Does the `find_element()` function count as a `GET` request?

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) initiated *Browsing Context* if gets detected as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) can be [*Rate Limited*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65136081/7429447) too.

Generally, *Cloudflare* rate-limits the visitor when the visitor traffic crosses the rate-limit thresholds which is calculated by, dividing 24 hours of uncached website requests by the unique visitors for the same 24 hours. Then, divide by the estimated average minutes of a visit.  Finally, multiply by 4 (or larger) to establish an estimated threshold per minute for your website. A value higher than 4 is fine since most attacks are an order of magnitude above typical traffic rates.